# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs' with webpack-cli 4.2.0

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I try to run webpack-dev-server it gives the error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs'
```

I looked around and found that you had to change the script to "webpack serve" and did that but then it gives me the following:

**[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$". BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict.    Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.**

My system is Windows 10 Pro and the versions are the following:

- webpack: 5.6.0
- webpack-cli: 4.2.0
- webpack-dev-server: 3.11.0

I've also tried including "inline: false" into the devServer object in webpack.config.js but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**just few step:**

- add script `"dev": "webpack serve"`
- set `devtool: 'eval-source-map'` in `webpack.config.js`
- then run `npm run dev` or `npx webpack serve`

`webpack v5 && webpack-cli v4` should use `webpack serve` instead of `webpack-dev-server`

if you run `npx webpack serve` come out

`configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$". BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict. Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.**`

you can set `devtool: 'eval-source-map'` in `webpack.config.js`

**usually to balance speed and debugging:**

- in `development` mode we use `devtool: 'eval-source-map'`
- in `production` mode we use `devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map'`

you can also return `webpack v4 && webpack-cli v3`
or try `npm i webpack-dev-server@4.0.0-beta.0 -D` 
see https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.0

more issues you can see

- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/1948
- https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2759

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will need to change `devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'` to `devtool: 'eval-source-map'`